# Apache have any limit of request per second and how to increase it?

Tags: php, request, apache2

On my server(Amazon EC2) cpu and mysql are use very low resource(Arround 10% CPU) but my server is only able to handle 150 request per second.

I was already increase value on mpm_prefork_module but  facing same problem.

Any have idea about which i wass missing on server configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the basic EC2 instance type like t2-nano or so on, which provides very less memory and processing power, then you will have less request management and requests/response per seconds. if more than that it will stop the server or hangs the VM. check the instances of EC2 and details regarding the CPU (you can check requests per seconds as per selected cpu) and memory.
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

It is more better to use nginx if you want more requests per second and processing through nginx. Nginx can handle 4 time more concurrent request handle rather than apache

Answer (score 0):

I believe the info you need is located here

[increase-apache-requests-per-second](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/increase-apache-requests-per-second/)

It looks like you already have MPM module installed which should make things easier.